# how to check if a variable is null or not?

Tags: android, null, textview

Hi I need to check the value of two variables if they are null or not.if they are not null i have to make a textview visible.for the same i have written the below code

```
 if (offer.Price() != null ) {
        if(offer.getName() !=null)
        {
        Price.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Price.setText(offer.getName()+" Price: $"+offer.getPrice());
    }
    }
```

but it is not working.ie the textview is visible even if the variable value is null and the text in the textview is displaying as "null Price: $null".first i tried with the below code.but that is also not working

```
    if (offer.getPrice() != null && offer.getName() !=null) {
        Price.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Price.setText(offer.getName()+" Price: $"+offer.getPrice());
    }
```

please help me to fix it....

Comment: what's the meaning of this: offer.Price()? Fix it when you read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Comment: its not variables its methods.. if they "return NULL;" they'll be equal to null.

Comment: oh..it was my mistake..that was a function..offer.price() is a mistake.it is offer.getPrice() and my problem is if(offer.getPrice()!=null) condition is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try that:

```
if (offer.getPrice() != null && offer.getName() !=null) {
        Price.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Price.setText(offer.getName()+" Price: $"+offer.getPrice());
    }else{
 Price.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

or that

```
if (offer.getPrice() != null && offer.getName() !=null
&& !offer.getPrice().equals("null") && !offer.getName().equals("null")) {
        Price.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Price.setText(offer.getName()+" Price: $"+offer.getPrice());
    }else{
 Price.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: !offer.getPrice().equals("null") has some magic... :)

Comment: @seethalakshmi, yea, Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (offer.getPrice() != null && !"".equalsIgnoreCase(offer.getPrice())
    && offer.getName() !=null && !"".equalsIgnoreCase(offer.getName())) {
    Price.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Price.setText(offer.getName()+" Price: $"+offer.getPrice());
}
```

Comment: why dont you simply use **TextUtils.isEmpty** instead of those long checks?

Comment: Indeed.. :D
public static boolean isEmpty(CharSequence str) {
         if (str == null || str.length() == 0)
             return true;
        else
             return false;
    }
So guess that makes more sense.. Thanks Waqas

Comment: i have tried with TextUtils.isEmpty but that is also not working

Comment: please check for offer.getPrice().trim(); and offer.getName().trim(); may be you are getting space as values thats why you are having issues.

Comment: i think you are calling webservice, so it  may be possible that you are getting value of "Price:" as "null". note: here null means text not null(empty).